# How can I share particular row of my spreadsheet in Google docs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have made attendance sheet of my students in Google docs . Now I want to share their weekly attendance sheet with them but I want to share only particular row of individual student to them. So that they are not able to see attendance of class mates.
Is this possible.? 
I can hide the rows but doing this for 120 students everytime is time taking.
?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to find a Google Sheets plugin that lets you generate emails. If you include the email address of the student in the row with their data, you can use commercially available plugins to use the content of the row as the body of the email and the email address of the student as the 'send to' address.
A search for 'email' in the 'get add-ons' part of sheets should help you along with this. I have done similar things before and it works quite well. Good luck!

Comment: Thank You So Much .

Comment: Please see my question again below

Answer (score 0):

I used the following ATTACHED CODE.
But I can only send one row using this : Name AttendanceinSub1. I want to send multiplr rows like: Name AttendanceinSub1 AttendanceinSub2 AttendanceinSub3. Can you suggest something?
[image]